# Weblogic to accept requests on all the IPs

Tags: weblogic

I have a **Weblogic** server configured.
But I want to know how to define weblogic to accept requests on *all the IPs available* on a particular server?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not provide an explicit listen address for weblogic server, then it listens on all the available IP's on the machine by default.
Setting a Listen Address binds wls to the particular IP the listen address resolves to.

If you cant remove the listen address thats configured then you can create a network channel which will explicitly listen on the other IP's